# CLisp: "use-package" resolving conflicts non-interactively

Tags: package, common-lisp

I'm trying to use parenscript in GNU common lisp to compile a lisp file into a javascript one.

I find that using the PS symbol macro "@" doesn't work if I try to use its prefix ("ps:@"). However, if I use the REPL and run (use-package :ps) before I try compiling the lisp file, everything works as expected (and I don't have to use the prefixes).

The problem is that the PS package contains clashing symbols, e.g:

```
*** - (USE-PACKAGE (#<PACKAGE PARENSCRIPT>) #<PACKAGE COMMON-LISP-USER>): 2 name conflicts remain  
  Which symbol with name "CHAIN" should be accessible in #<PACKAGE COMMON-LISP-USER>?  
  The following restarts are available:  
PARENSCRIPT    :R1      #<PACKAGE PARENSCRIPT>  
COMMON-LISP-USER :R2    #<PACKAGE COMMON-LISP-USER>  
ABORT          :R3      Abort main loop
```

I can resolve this interactively by choosing :r1, but when I try to put this step in my script it just bails (since it's non-interactive, it doesn't give me a choice of what restart to use)

I'd love to say (in my script) "just use the PS version of all clashing symbols", but I can't figure out how to do so.

It would also be okay if I could say (as one might in python), "from PS import chain, @, (etc)" - specifying each symbol I want to import manually.

Comment: Can you show your package definitions resp. "import statements"?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What do you want me to show?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of working in the COMMON-LISP-USER package, make your own with DEFPACKAGE:

```
(defpackage #:my-awesome-program
  (:use #:cl #:parenscript))

(in-package #:my-awesome-program)

; your code here
```

COMMON-LISP-USER might include all sorts of implementation-specific symbols.

You can also use SHADOWING-IMPORT to get individual symbols, overriding what might already be currently visible in the package, e.g.

```
(shadowing-import 'ps:*)
```

Comment: I've put that at the top of my file called "compiler.lisp", subbing "my-awesome-program" for "compiler":

[1]> (load "compiler.lisp")
>> RENAME-PACKAGE("SYSTEM"): #<PACKAGE SYSTEM> is locked

if I continue, ignoring this error, I get: USE-PACKAGE: There is no package with name "COMPILER".

Is (load "compiler.lisp") the wrong function? should I require it or something else?

Comment: The shadowing-import thing worked, thanks! I'm not sure what I've done to make the package stuff not work, I'll have to figure that out sometime later...

Comment: I'd have to see your file. The error message doesn't make sense just from your description of it.

Comment: I take it you're using clisp as your implementation? It comes with a package called COMPILER already defined (it's a nickname for the package SYSTEM).

Comment: How can I SHADOWING-IMPORT a list of symbols from a package? I'd rather not call this for every symbol separately.